# Maintain DbContext Across N-Tier App

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I am trying to convert an N-Layer architecture to a new N-Tier architecture which is able to maintain a DbContext across multiple tiers. Currently my app has the following high level architecture (I can't add images yet so please forgive my diagram):

```
View <--> Controller <--> Model <--> Repository <--> Database
```

The controller, model, and repository all use a transaction class that I wrote which abstracts the DbContext away from the controller and model, but allows one DbContext to be shared across multiple models. In code, this might look like:

```
using(ITransaction transaction = new Transaction())
{
    var parent = new Parent();
    var child = new Child();
    parent.Children.Add(child);
    parent.Insert(transaction);
    parent.Save();
}
```

The Insert function goes all the way from the controller to the repository (the only thing that actually knows how to insert), and then the Save function goes back to the repository and commits the changes.

This architecture that I want is as follows:

```
View <--> Controller <--> Model <--> WFC Service <--> Repository <--> Database
```

When I add the WFC service between the model and the repository, I continuously get System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Personally I'd keep the context as limited as possible and definitely don't let it leak from the back end to the front end.

Comment: I don't think the context technically "leaks" from the backend to the front end because my controller doesn't know it is carrying the DbContext. The controller and model both work with non-EF classes and lists, so I can remove EF without any code changes in my controller and/or models. The repository would need to be changed, as well as the transaction class, but that was by design.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that's worth making your application slower, more complicated, and less reliable?

Comment: David - Are you asking what the benefits of N-Tier are, or are you asking why I want to pass a DbContext?